# download from ubuntu apps directory

Tags: downloads, gimp

I am trying to download GIMP from ubuntu apps directory. When i click on download it opens a windows launch application window. What do I have to do for that?Do I need to download an application for this application.

Comment: select `/usr/bin/software-center`

Comment: What's the download link that you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to open the Ubuntu Software Center and install Gimp from there.

Otherwise follow Avinash Raj's comment.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to select the Ubuntu Software Center to open apt links:

[image]

Click on "Choose..." and type the full path `/usr/bin/software-center` in the location field (Click on the small pen if it's not visible):

[image]